# how to publish jekyll website to github pages

Tags: git, jekyll, github-pages

i'm in trouble managing git with my jekyll project, I do not understand how to work with jekyll, git and gitub pages.
My repo is here: https://github.com/smorele/smorele.github.io
My website content (the _site folder) should be served but it's the index.html from the root which is used.
As explained in the differents ressources i've read, i've created a `gh-pages` branch but I do not undertand what is the usage.

My questions:

- how to serve the `_site` repository ?
- what is the git process when I create a new page ? How do I have to manage branchs ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I checked your repo link and it's either private or it doesn't exist. I checked your other repos and it looks like you're trying to host your coaching site on github pages (https://github.com/smorele/coaching). You need a few things:

1. Include your repo name in the baseurl variable in the `config.yml` file
2. Use your `gh-pages` branch as your publushing github page in settings

Comment: thans for your help. I did some tests since my request and the correct repo is now https://github.com/smorele/coaching_website
I did what you suggest but I do not understand how things goes when it builds. the gh-pages is never populated with the _site content

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the gh-pages branch anymore. Just go to **Settings**, scroll to **GitHub Pages** and set the dropdown to 'master' where it says:

> Source
>     Your GitHub Pages site is currently being built from the '[...]' branch. Learn more.

That is all!

Answer (score 0):

You can check out https://technokami.in/setup-github-pages-site-with-free-domain where I try to explain exactly this :)